# psql editor setting on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, psql

The situation is the following.  This is an Ubuntu box:

```
Linux ns3mx3 2.6.32-41-server #89-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 27 22:33:31 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Which means that when I first issue `\e` in `psql`, I'm asked to choose an editor.  Then there is the `.selected_editor` file, which contains

```
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/mcedit-debian"
```

So far this is OK (it's my problem that I consider this completely useless, but never mind).

Then I set up a `.psqlrc` file:

```
\set PSQL_EDITOR /usr/bin/vim
\set EDITOR /usr/bin/vim
\set VISUAL /usr/bin/vim
```

As you can see, I wanted to be sure not to miss a candidate variable for editor setting.  The file is used as expected:

```
test=# \echo :EDITOR
/usr/bin/vim
```

But when I issue the `\e` command, none of these is used - I fall back to `SELECTED_EDITOR`.  The situation remains just the same if I append an `\unset SELECTED_EDITOR` to the `.psqlrc` file.

Now how can I make `.psqlrc` setting win over the default editor?

(PostgreSQL version id 9.1.4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can understand by reading the `psql` documentation, `PSQL_EDITOR`, `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` are supposed to be shell environment variables. Therefore you should set them, for example, in your `.bashrc`, by adding the following line:

```sh
export PSQL_EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
```

I have tested this by executing the following command line (which sets the given environment variable just for the executed command):

```sh
PSQL_EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano psql
```

and when I executed the `\e` command in `psql`, `nano` was correctly executed as the editor, even though my default selected editor is `vim`.